# Why use socket.broadcast.emit function over socket.emit

Tags: websocket, socket.io, serversocket

I know what the difference is the broadcast function sends an event to everyone but the client who caused it and the casual emit sends it to everyone. I don't see why someone would use it. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

`io.sockets.emit` will send to all the clients.

`socket.broadcast.emit` will send the message to all the other clients except the newly created connection.